# print function return value in data-table

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

I am using `jQuery` datatable, in which I have to print count. that count is coming from the other URL. Here is my try:

```
{
        "aTargets": [ 6 ],
        "fnCreatedCell": function(nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol)
        {
          $("a", nTd).tooltip();
        },
        "mRender": function ( data, type, full )
        {
          var v = 'http://localhost/test6/count/'+full['id']+'';
          return '<a style="color:#38BDB6;" href="http://localhost/test6/count/'+full['id']+'" class="">'+v+'</a>';
        }
      },
```

I have function in `controller` with name `count`. That function returns the count. But in data-table it is printing URL like `http://localhost/test6/count/12`.

Comment: what u want instead of  this url "http://localhost/test6/count/12"

Comment: @DivyeshChothani there should be count for id `12`

Comment: yah but count means only "count" word or what?

Comment: no.. count means integer like `11` something like that

Comment: please alert(full)  this after what u have get and tell me..

Comment: It's unclear what you're willing to achieve...

Comment: @OfirBaruch i have one function count in controller it will return count of total records from the table and i have to display it in datatable